# Merging tables with same name and schema in different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table A in UAT with the following schema

```
A-UAT

Column 1,
Column 2,
Column 3
```

I have the same table in prod with the same schema

```
A-Prod

Column 1,
Column 2,
Column 3
```

New rows were added to UAT recently and at that time UAT did not have all the records of the Prod table. Now, I want to merge the newly added rows in UAT with prod. That is, whatever was newly added in UAT alone should go into prod without disturbing whatever was existing there already. Is there a way to do this in MS SQL server 2005/08?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are only interested in new rows, not updated rows, and that your table has a primary key:

```
INSERT dbo.[A-Prod](all cols except IDENTITY column) 
SELECT all cols except IDENTITY column FROM dbo.[A-UAT] AS x
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[A-Prod] 
    WHERE key = x.key
  );
```

You can also limit the `SELECT` by date/time if such a column exists.

If the table has an IDENTITY column, and you need to maintain those values, and assuming that *no new rows have been inserted in production*, you can say:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[A-Prod] ON;

INSERT dbo.[A-Prod](all cols)
SELECT all cols FROM dbo.[A-UAT] AS x
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[A-Prod] 
    WHERE identity_column = x.identity_column
  );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.[A-Prod] OFF;
```

If there have been any new rows inserted in production, then it is likely you will need to perform some manual work to resolve any conflicts.

Comment: Aaron, thanks a lot. Will this work even if the tables have an auto incrementing/auto generated primary key?

Comment: @Sai do you need the original values to be the same, or do you just need the new rows to get *some* identity value in production? If the former, it might not be possible if new rows have been inserted into production in the meantime, without some really creative massaging of the data.

Comment: I would need some identity value in production not the exact same one as in UAT. You have addressed my concern in your response yourself :) I am lucky it is not the former because we are constantly adding other rows to prod.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response :) And, these are not actual table names.